# Mouse problems with VCXSrv Qemu-kvm Virt-manager

Tags: mouse

I am running some Windows-based virtual machines under qemu-kvm on a server that I access from my Windows 10 desktop through SSH Via Putty.  I have VCXsrv installed on my desktop and SSH forwarding set up in Putty.  When I run virt-manager while connected via SSH, everything in virt-manager works correctly.  I can create and manage machines, etc.  However, when I open one of my Windows virtual machines through virt-manager, my mouse repeatedly jumps to the upper right corner of the console window, and the cursor will move in small increments in the virtual machine, but not very far.  Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Found my own answer.  Added a tablet input hardware device to the virtual machine with absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are virt-manager you can follow below picture to add a "input" device with type of "EvTouch USB Graphics Tablet"

[image]